# Trying to loop over and extract the names from the table

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is the code I have and I am trying to crack it with jQuery to extract the names inside the td elements

In some cases the td is empty and I want to merge the 1 td on the left side with the 5 td of right side because the 5td on right side have the first td as empty and have record in the second td

I am only concerned with TD, not with TH

Here is the code [with help of somebody, I am able to reach till here]

```js
table = doc.select("##warranty-information");
trs = table.select("tr");
for(i = 0; i < trs.size(); i++) {
  tds = trs.get(i).select("td");
  for(j = 0; j < tds.size(); j++) {
    trs.get(0).tds.get(j).text()
    trs.get(i).tds.get(1).text() 
    WriteDump( tds.get(j).text() );
  }
  /*
  if( tds.size() ) {
    form[ tds.get(0).text() ] = tds.get(1).text();
  }
  */
}
```

```html
<table id="warranty-information">
  <tr>
    <th colspan="2" class="ui-corner-top">Warranty Information</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="vertical-align: top;">Warranty</td>
    <td style="vertical-align: top;">2 Years</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="2" class="ui-corner-top">Hardware</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="vertical-align: top;">Adapter Style</td>
    <td style="vertical-align: top;">Cable Adapters</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="vertical-align: top;">Converter Type</td>
    <td style="vertical-align: top;">Cable Adapters</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="vertical-align: top;">Output Signal</td>
    <td style="vertical-align: top;">DisplayPort</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="vertical-align: top;">Included in Package</td>
    <td style="vertical-align: top;">1 - SATA hard drive docking station </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="border-top: 0;vertical-align: top;"></td>
    <td style="border-top: 0;vertical-align: top;">1 - USB Cable </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="border-top: 0;vertical-align: top;"></td>
    <td style="border-top: 0;vertical-align: top;">2 - eSATA Cable </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="border-top: 0;vertical-align: top;"></td>
    <td style="border-top: 0;vertical-align: top;">1 - Power Adapter </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="border-top: 0;vertical-align: top;"></td>
    <td style="border-top: 0;vertical-align: top;">1 - Instruction Manual </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: `doc.select("##warranty-information");` `WriteDump`? how is that jQuery? I think you need a tag - like jSoup or something

Comment: Can you give all the `TD`s you want info from a `class` name?  It would be much easier to loop through using `.each` -- And +1 to @mplungjan --  You're not using jQuery, however you COULD --> `$('.your_class').html();` would much be more effective at getting the internal text in the `TD`

Answer (score 1):

You are probably better off doing this manually as there isn't a good way to sort format the table data due to the irregular usage. but you could use something like this.

```js
const data = [...document.querySelectorAll('td')].map(x => x.innerText)
const obj = { "Included in Package": [] }

for (let ii = 1, ll = data.length; ii < ll; ii+=2) {
  const key = data[ii - 1]
  const value = data[ii]
  if (key === "" || key === "Included in Package") {
    obj["Included in Package"].push(value)
  }
  else {
    obj[key] = value
  }
}

console.log(obj)
```

```css
td {
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<table id="warranty-information">
  <tr>
    <th colspan="2" class="ui-corner-top">Warranty Information</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="vertical-align: top;">Warranty</td>
    <td style="vertical-align: top;">2 Years</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="2" class="ui-corner-top">Hardware</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="vertical-align: top;">Adapter Style</td>
    <td style="vertical-align: top;">Cable Adapters</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="vertical-align: top;">Converter Type</td>
    <td style="vertical-align: top;">Cable Adapters</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="vertical-align: top;">Output Signal</td>
    <td style="vertical-align: top;">DisplayPort</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="vertical-align: top;">Included in Package</td>
    <td style="vertical-align: top;">1 - SATA hard drive docking station </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="border-top: 0;vertical-align: top;"></td>
    <td style="border-top: 0;vertical-align: top;">1 - USB Cable </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="border-top: 0;vertical-align: top;"></td>
    <td style="border-top: 0;vertical-align: top;">2 - eSATA Cable </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="border-top: 0;vertical-align: top;"></td>
    <td style="border-top: 0;vertical-align: top;">1 - Power Adapter </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="border-top: 0;vertical-align: top;"></td>
    <td style="border-top: 0;vertical-align: top;">1 - Instruction Manual </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty easy using jQuery.

```js
let names = $('#warranty-information')
  .find('td')
  .map((i, el) => $(el).text().trim()) // map jQuery array to text of each element
  .get() // convert to normal array
  .filter(text => !!text); // filter not empty text

console.log(names);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="warranty-information">
  <tr>
    <th colspan="2" class="ui-corner-top">Warranty Information</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="vertical-align: top;">Warranty</td>
    <td style="vertical-align: top;">2 Years</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="2" class="ui-corner-top">Hardware</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="vertical-align: top;">Adapter Style</td>
    <td style="vertical-align: top;">Cable Adapters</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="vertical-align: top;">Converter Type</td>
    <td style="vertical-align: top;">Cable Adapters</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="vertical-align: top;">Output Signal</td>
    <td style="vertical-align: top;">DisplayPort</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="vertical-align: top;">Included in Package</td>
    <td style="vertical-align: top;">1 - SATA hard drive docking station </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="border-top: 0;vertical-align: top;"></td>
    <td style="border-top: 0;vertical-align: top;">1 - USB Cable </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="border-top: 0;vertical-align: top;"></td>
    <td style="border-top: 0;vertical-align: top;">2 - eSATA Cable </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="border-top: 0;vertical-align: top;"></td>
    <td style="border-top: 0;vertical-align: top;">1 - Power Adapter </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="border-top: 0;vertical-align: top;"></td>
    <td style="border-top: 0;vertical-align: top;">1 - Instruction Manual </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```